# AWS S3 multiple file upload from browser. Exception handle to uploading multiple files decide for which file the error has occurred from its error obj

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am uploading multiple files to AWS s3 from browser using its aws-sdk.

I can get progress status for each file by its event ['httpuploadProgress'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html) and can differentiate for which file is the progress status by using its event property 'key' which gives the unique files name.

But when an exception happens in its exception handling object I see no property to uniquely identify for which file the exception has occurred. Can anybody tell how to get the value for which file the exception has occurred?

Here is my current code.

```
var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
  params: {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key,
    Body: file,
  },
});

upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {
  // update progress logic in dom
});

var promise = upload.promise();
promise.then(
  (data) => {
    // upload completion logic
  },
  function (err) {
    //=> here exception hits,
    // this err object has does not have any property to uniquely identify the file for which therror occured
  }
);
}
```